# Why Google Cloud Storage quickstart.py works on google cloud shell but not on Google App Engine?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Google Cloud Storage quickstart.py works on Google Cloud Shell but not on Google App Engine

quickstart.py

```
def run_quickstart():
    # [START storage_quickstart]
    # Imports the Google Cloud client library
    from google.cloud import storage
    # Instantiates a client
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket_name = 'mygoolgeappproject.appspot.com'
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blobs = bucket.list_blobs()`enter code here`
    for blob in blobs:
        print(blob.name)
    # The name for the new bucket
    #bucket_name = 'mygoolgeappproject.appspot.com'
    # Creates the new bucket
    #bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name)
    #print('Bucket {} created.'.format(bucket.name))
    # [END storage_quickstart]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_quickstart()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't run a plain python script like `quickstart.py` directly as an GAE app. Different tools for different purposes.

You need a basic GAE app skeleton. You can find a sample skeleton in the [Hello World code review](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/quickstart#hello_world_code_review).